# Prevent asciidoctor from doing ellipsis replacement in inline literal

Tags: asciidoctor

I'm trying to render the following chunk with asciidoctor (PDF, EPUB and MOBI output formats):

```
* `versionMin...versionMax`
* `versionMin...<versionMax`
```

I want this to appear as a bullet list where the text is monospaced. The problem I have at the moment is that I can't seem to prevent asciidoctor from replacing the `...` with ellipses (they end up vertically centred). I've tried various incantations of `pass[]`, `+...+`, etc. but can't seem to find a combination that works. Anyone able to show how to prevent the ellipsis replacement without interfering with any of the other processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three solutions that worked for me (for your first bullet):

```
* `versionMin\...versionMax`
* `versionMin&period;..versionMax`
* `versionMin&#46;..versionMax`
```

My first solution is discussed in https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#preventing-substitutions.

The second solution uses a named entity and the third uses a numeric entity. Info about HTML character entities is at https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML.

Comment: Seems the output format potentially matters, so I updated my question with that info. The backslash and &#46; works, but the &period; is rejected with an error. I had tried various backslash combinations but it seems I missed the simplest. :P